# Merging http observables using forkjoin

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, observable

I'm trying to avoid nested observables by using `forkjoin`. The current (nested) version looks like this:

```
  this.http.get('https://testdb1.firebaseio.com/.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data_changes => {
    this.http.get('https://testdb2.firebaseio.com/.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data_all => {
      /* Do this once resolved */
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.storage.set('data_changes', data_changes);
        this.storage.set('data_all', data_all);
        document.getElementById("chart").innerHTML = "";
        this.createChart();
      });
    });
  },

    err => {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        console.log("server error 2");
        document.getElementById("chart").innerHTML = "";
        this.createChart();
      });
    });
  }
```

I can rewrite the first part as:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get('https://testdb1.firebaseio.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('https://testdb2.firebaseio.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json())
)
```

But i'm not sure how I would then add the `.subscribe` method to access both `data_changes` and `data_all`.

Looking at another example, I know it should look something like `.subscribe(res => this.combined = {friends:res[0].friends, customer:res[1]});`, but i'm not sure how to adapt this to my example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try to use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin` :

**With `combineLatest` :**

```
const combined = Observable.combineLatest(
  this.http.get('https://testdb1.firebaseio.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('https://testdb2.firebaseio.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json())
)

combined.subscribe(latestValues => {
    const [ data_changes , data_all ] = latestValues;
    console.log( "data_changes" , data_changes);
    console.log( "data_all" , data_all);
});
```

You can also handle it by forkJoin , but forkJoin will return data when all calls are finished and return result , but in combineLatest When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.

**With `forkJoin` :**

```
const combined = Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get('https://testdb1.firebaseio.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('https://testdb2.firebaseio.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json())
)

combined.subscribe(latestValues => {
    const [ data_changes , data_all ] = latestValues;
    console.log( "data_changes" , data_changes);
    console.log( "data_all" , data_all);
});
```

Call both and check the console log , you will get idea.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation of why the OP should favour `combineLatest`.

Comment: Okay , just one minute.

Comment: If you find out this helpfull , please accept the answer also.

Comment: Your description of the behaviour of `combineLatest` is incorrect. It won't emit anything until each of the observables it's passed has emitted at least once. And the HTTP observables will emit only once, so how will using it differ from using `forkJoin`, if at all?

Comment: Yes I know, i think I coundn't explain it very well

Comment: @VivekDoshi will combine latest with work different model httpclients ?

Like httpclient.get<Customer> and httpclient.get<Employee> can this be combined ?

Comment: @Eldho, yes it will.

Comment: i tried but its not working, it show like `this.Employee` cannot be set with `customer`

Comment: A side note, `forkJoin` will only trigger when the observables return a new value after your call `forkJoin`, so if one of the observables has already returned a value `forkJoin` will never trigger next. `combineLatest` will trigger even if the observable has already emitted its value. Thought this might help someone if who comes across this page and can't figure out why their subscribe next function is never being it.