# Angular 2: How to force run a function after all services are ready?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

```
export class InferencePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private campaignService: CampaignService) {
    this.campaignService.getStrategy1().subscribe(data => {
      this.Strategy1 = data;
    });
    this.campaignService.getStrategy2().subscribe(data => {
      this.Strategy2 = data;
  });
    this.campaignService.getStrategy3().subscribe(data => {
      this.Strategy3 = data;
    });
  }
```

I have data coming from 3 different functions of a service as above. I also have a function that takes data loaded from these 3 services and does some processing on that. But I am not able to load the function after all these 3 services have fully loaded. 
What should be the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

You   handle it by **[`forkJoin`](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)** ,forkJoin will return data when all calls are finished and return result

You handle all these calls inside a service using forkJoin and subscribe it inside the component, once you get the data you can call the other function.

[`Merging http observables using forkjoin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166214/merging-http-observables-using-forkjoin)

which would be the best way to solve it, also you can use **[`observable.zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining)** to do it on your component itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Observable.zip() , 
Below is the code snippet that can help you.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/zip';
// then in your component, do as below :
Observable.zip( 
 this.campaignService.getStrategy1(),
 this.campaignService.getStrategy2(),
 this.campaignService.getStrategy3()
 ).subscribe(([Strategy1Data,Strategy2Data, Strategy3Data])) => {
   this.Strategy1  = Strategy1Data;
   this.Strategy2 = Strategy2Data;
   this.Strategy3 = Strategy3Data;
   this.yourFunctionForExtraProcess();
 }
```