# Subscribe to multiple async http calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

on ngOnInit i make 4 http request for data, after that i need to load the data from server to fill the forms with the data based on data model of last 4 http call.

In short words i need to subscribe to this 4 http calls, and make sure don't fail if they don't fail finally i can call the 5th http call to get data from server.

From what i understand, i should avoid to inest a observable and go with switch, but how to do this with 4 http call? should i create an observable wait for the http calls and if succed to use switchmap on the 5th http call?

This is the code.

```
      ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getProvince().subscribe(
        (value) => { return value; },
        (error: AppError) => {
            if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
                console.log('Error richiesta http');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });


    this.service.getLingueStraniere().subscribe(
        (value) => { return value; },
        (error: AppError) => {
            if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
                console.log('Error richiesta http');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    this.service.getTitoliPreferenziali().subscribe(
        (value) => { return value; },
        (error: AppError) => {
            if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
                console.log('Error richiesta http');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    this.service.getRiserve().subscribe(
        (value) => { return value; },
        (error: AppError) => {
            if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
                console.log('Error richiesta http');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}


// this is the 5th call that need to be done only if last 4 call not fail

finalCall {
    this.service.getDomanda().subscribe((domanda: any) => {
        this.popolaForm(domanda); // Method that use data to fill foms
    },
        (error: AppError) => {
            if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
                console.log('Error richiesta http');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You could use [forkJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166214/merging-http-observables-using-forkjoin) to merge your requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to combine all the requests and get the results as callback when all the requests are completed.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
 forkJoin([this.service.getProvince(),this.service.getLingueStraniere(),this.service.getTitoliPreferenziali(), this.service.getRiserve()])
     .pipe(switchMap(result => { 
          console.log('Province', result[0]);
          console.log('LingueStraniere', result[1]);
          console.log('TitoliPreferenziali', result[2]);
          console.log('Riserve', result[3]);
          return this.service.getDomanda();
      }))
      .subscribe((domanda: any) => {
         console.log('getDomanda', domanda);
       });                                                          
}
```

Comment: All answers were good, but i feel your is the cleanest and best  RXJS way. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). It waits for all observables to be completed, before emitting the last emitted value from each request. `forkJoin` throws an error if any of the observables throws an error.

```
let callOne = this.service.getLingueStraniere();
let callTwo = this.service.getTitoliPreferenziali();
 .
 .
 .
forkJoin([callOne, callTwo]).subscribe(response => {
  //handle success response
}, (error) => {
    // error handling
}, () => {
    // when observable is completed
});
```

You may read more about `forkJoin` over [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

Answer (score -1):

I would transform those **subscriptions** to promises using **.toPromise()** so you can wait for all 4 http requests to be completed and then fill the form.
It is not a fully running example but the idea is said.

```
try {
    ... await this.service.getProvince().toPromise();
    ... await this.service.getTitoliPreferenziali().toPromise();
    ... await this.service.getLingueStraniere().toPromise();
    ... await this.service.getRiserve().toPromise();
    //fill form
}catch(error) {
 //show error message or do something like retry calls
}
```

Comment: We don't necessarily convert all those into promises for this use cases, we can just use any of the combinational operators available in rxjs.