# Chain two selects rxjs store in Angular Guard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to select two fields from the ngrx store in an Angular Guard like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    private store: Store<AppState> ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    const expectedRole = route.data.Role;

    return combineLatest(
        this.store.pipe(select(isLoggedIn)),
        this.store.pipe(select(currentUser)),
      ).pipe(
          tap( ([loggedIn, user]) => 
                {
                    if ( loggedIn && !(user.role.find(expectedRole) >= 0) ) {
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/error/403')
                    };
                }
            )
        );


  }

}
```

However, I'm getting `Type 'boolean | [any, any]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`, which makes sense, since the combineLatest return the result in array. But I can't seem to find a more elegant way than combineLatest, instead of nesting the two select observable, what would be my alternatives here?

Comment: Try to force type `([loggedIn, user]: [boolean, User])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscribe to multiple async http calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457374/subscribe-to-multiple-async-http-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canActivate` method should return a `boolean` wrapped in an `Observable`. As per your code, it is returning the values wrapped in an `Observable` returned from the `combineLatest` method which is an array. You can use `map` operator to return `true` or `false` like this:

```
@Injectable()

export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    private store: Store<AppState> ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    const expectedRole = route.data.Role;

    return combineLatest(
        this.store.pipe(select(isLoggedIn)),
        this.store.pipe(select(currentUser)),
      ).pipe(
          map( ([loggedIn, user]) => 
                {
                    if ( loggedIn && !(user.role.find(expectedRole) >= 0) ) {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/error/403')
                      //I am assuming that you want to fail the guard and want your application to route to 403 page, so let’s return false
                      return false;
                    };

                  //I am assuming that you want to pass the guard of above if condition fails, so return true; bottom line is to return true/false as per your logic.
                  return true;

                }
            )

);
  }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkJoin

```
forkJoin([
        this.store.pipe(select(isLoggedIn)),
        this.store.pipe(select(currentUser)),
      ])
```

Or merge operator

> Creates an output Observable which concurrently emits all values from
>   every given input Observable.

```
import { merge, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const timer1 = interval(1000).pipe(take(10));
const timer2 = interval(2000).pipe(take(6));
const timer3 = interval(500).pipe(take(10));
const concurrent = 2; // the argument
const merged = merge(timer1, timer2, timer3, concurrent);
merged.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: for some reason ```forkJoin``` didn't execute the function in the map, though ```combineLatest``` did, not sure why https://gist.github.com/yehiasalam/c364423bca07170a61c343fa2d9157c6

Answer (score 1):

forkJoin can be used when both service are independent & is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each.
If response of one service is used/consumed by other service then below code snippet will work.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

return this.store.pipe(select(isLoggedIn)).pipe(switchMap(loggedIn)=>{
     return _checkLoggedIn(loggedIn);
   }),
   catchError(() => {
      return of(false);
    }));
}


private _checkLoggedIn(loggedIn): Observable<boolean>{
  if(loggedIn){
    return of(true);
  }else{
    return this.store.pipe(select(currentUser)).pipe(map((currentUser)=>{
      return currentUser;
    }));
  }
}
```