# Waiting for all HTTP Request to return before proceeding with another function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to wait for three HTTP requests to complete before calling another function to work on the data returned by the three HTTP requests.

I tried looping the number of rooms (equivalent to the number of HTTP requests required) and then pushing the devices into an array. I need all three HTTP requests to be completed before passing the array of devices to the next function to work on.

```
getDeviceListByRoom(rooms_id_array: string[]) {
    console.log('The rooms_id_array is: ', rooms_id_array);
    this.room_device_map = new Map;
    let count = 0;
    for (const id of rooms_id_array) {
      const devicesByRoom = this.Services.getDeviceByRoom(id);
      devicesByRoom.subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res.code === 200) {
          // this statement will map the list of devices to the room.
          this.room_device_map.set(id, res.data);

          // this statement will just push the list of devices from different room into one array.
          this.all_devices_list.push(res.data);
          console.log('count is: ', count++);
        }
      }, err => {
        console.error('ERROR', err);
      });
      console.log('In all_devices_list is: ', this.all_devices_list);
    }
    console.log('Lalalalal');
  }

The code above will return 'Lalalala' first followed by the console print out of the count variable. Understandably, the for...of function is non blocking...?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscribe to multiple async http calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457374/subscribe-to-multiple-async-http-calls)

Answer (score 1):

`forkJoin` is your friend.

(am on mobile, sorry for my brevity)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is 'forkJoin', in such situations you can use 'zip' or 'combineLatest' too.

Try this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

...

let req1 = this.http.get('xxx');
let req2 = this.http.get('yyy');

forkJoin([req1, req2]).subscribe(res => {
    // res[0] is from req1
    // res[1] is from req2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine latest will emit once all 3 requests have emitted

```
combineLatest(
  this.http.get('request1'),
  this.http.get('request2'),
  this.http.get('request3')
).subscribe(([response1, response2, response3]) => {
  // Here you can do stuff with response1, response2 and response3
});
```