# Receive data from multiple observables in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rxjs

I have 2 services. Both services have individual subjects and I am exposing both of them to other components by returning `asObservable`. Both have an `addDataN` function and both are emitting data to respecting subjects in services by on subject,so the `getdataN` method which is also emitting data on subject.

Now at the consumer side I am receiving two services completely independent. In component I am subscribing to the Listener, which are returning `asObservable`, and `getdataN` funnction, which are emitting data

> Serv1

```
  getdata1() {
    this.http.get<{message:string,Data1:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/1')
      .pipe(map((data1)=>{
        return Data1.Data1.map(data=>{
          return  {
            id: data._id,
            data1Title:data1.data1Title,
          }
        })
      })).subscribe((data1) => {
        this.data1=data1
        this.serv1Subject.next([...this.data1])
      })
  }
  addData1(){
       this.http.post<{message:string,Data1:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/1',dataObject)
       .subscribe((data)=>{
           this.data1=data1
        this.serv1Subject.next([...this.data1])
       })
  }

  getData1Listener() {
    return this.serv1Subject.asObservable()
  }
```

> Serv2

```
  getdata1() {
    this.http.get<{message:string,Data2:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/2')
      .pipe(map((data1)=>{
        return Data2.Data2.map(data=>{
          return  {
            id: data._id,
            data1Title:data1.data1Title,
          }
        })
      })).subscribe((data1) => {
        this.data1=data1
        this.serv2Subject.next([...this.data1])
      })
  }
  addData2(){
       this.http.post<{message:string,Data2:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/2',dataObject)
       .subscribe((data)=>{
           this.data1=data1
        this.serv2Subject.next([...this.data1])
       })
  }

  getData2Listener() {
    return this.serv2Subject.asObservable()
  }
```

Now at consumer component at `ngOnInit` at beginning I want to make sure that both subjects emit data and perform function `x` on data received from both end. And after that both work independently.

```
        ngOnInit(){
            this.serv1.getdata1()
            this.serv2.getdata2()
        combineLatest(this.serv1.getData1Listener(), this.serv2.getData2Listener())
.subscribe(([data1,data2])=>{function x(){
    something with data1,data2
    }})
    }
```

My Problem is with zip at beginning. Both work fine at beginning as both services emit, but after emitting data to `serv1` the other is not emitted anything so it stuck there.

In `withLatestFrom` only recent data is received and I want to avoid spread operator

Is there any way I can cleanly implement this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging http observables using forkjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166214/merging-http-observables-using-forkjoin)

Comment: @akash forkjoin works if the observables are  complete

Comment: @akash and i want to avoid the append the only latest data to existing data. is there any other way?

Comment: _after that both work independently_ - please show the component implementation.

Comment: @MichaelD i have edited the basic outline of ngOnInit

Comment: You're showing only the independent part. You say you've tried `zip` and `withLatestFrom`, please show them. What do you exactly mean by perform `x` on first emissions and after that behave independently?

Comment: now when at beginning i want to make sure both subject is emitted but after that they are independent cant do that with zip as zip require next on both subject creating dependency.

Comment: it looks like `combineLatest()` is what you need.  It will only emit once each source observable emits at least once, but after will emit any time either one emit (independently). But you are already using it! What behavior are you seeing? What behavior is desired?