# Is there any way to concat http response arrays, in just one array in angular 2

Tags: angular, http

I have this 2 arrays that a HTTP response in Angular 2, I need to convert this two arrays in just another one that is test5, but I seem unable to sum them, any other ideas?

this.test3= this.http
      .get("adresssAPI1")

this.test4 = this.http
      .get("adressAPI2")

this.test5 = this.test 3 + this.test4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Observable.combineLatest` or `Observable.forkJoin`, see their differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797439/rxjs-observable-combinelatest-vs-observable-forkjoin).

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.test3, this.test4);
Observable.forkJoin(this.test3, this.test4);
```

when you subscribe to `Observable.combineLatest`, you will get result like below:

```
[response3, response4]
```

and you can use `Array.reduce` to combine those two Observables' result

```
// combineLatest
Observable.combineLatest(this.test3, this.test4)
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.concatResult = res.reduce((pre, next) => {
      return [].concat(pre.json().data, next.json().data);
    })
  });

// forkJoin
Observable.forkJoin(this.test3, this.test4)
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.concatResult = res.reduce((pre, next) => {
      return [].concat(pre.json().data, next.json().data);
    })
  });
```

refer this **[plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/7ZaYuZOXuKC5TD4WZkDk?p=preview)**

Comment: I think `forkJoin` might be more suitable for http operations. Since `combineLatest` don't wait for observables to complete (leakage maybe?) AFAIK but not really sure if it would make a difference :-)

Comment: @echonax I'm not familiar with `forJoin`, let me learn it first. :P

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797439/rxjs-observable-combinelatest-vs-observable-forkjoin

Comment: @echonax thanks for the link. :) seems very close for those two operators.

Comment: @echonax I just run test on combineLatest and seems it'll also wait for all observables to complete. did I miss anything since it's behavior is different from the link you provided(as I understand)?  you can check on this https://plnkr.co/edit/7ZaYuZOXuKC5TD4WZkDk?p=preview

Comment: That's an awesome test :-) I approach `combineLatest` with caution since it seems to me that it's designed for more continuous stuff like websocket events/streams. Just wanted to point that out :-)

Comment: @echonax I agree with you about `continuous` :)