# How to merge multiple RxJS AjaxObservable calls to make a single observable?

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs

I have an **Angular 4** app with a *product list component* that displays the names of the products. The names of the products are retrieved from the server API. There are 1000 products which has to be retrieved in a few ajax calls [`AjaxObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts). Every call return 200 products, so have to make 5 calls to return all the products.

How can I achieve the above with [`AjaxObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts)? Should I merge all the observables or create single only and allow the UI to subscribe?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var source = Rx.Observable.ajax({ url: 'products', method: 'GET' });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md

```
let obs1: Observable<any> = Observable.of('val1', 'val2');
let obs2: Observable<any> = Observable.of('val3', 'val4');
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(obs1, obs2).subscribe(values => {
    console.log(values) //values is array - this statement will print [val2, val4]
});
```

Also you could take a look at this answer: [Rxjs: Observable.combineLatest vs Observable.forkJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797439/rxjs-observable-combinelatest-vs-observable-forkjoin)