# Using multiple services to populate Angular Data-Table

Tags: angular, http, datatable, angular-material, observable

I am using a few backend services to populate three columnns with Material Designs data table. I am using an observable to populate the data Source data. but how do I include the data from the other services. So far I am only able to use data from one Service. My thought process was to use a .push to the data Source.

```
dataSource = []

constructor(public data: xService, public otherData: yService) { }

submit() {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource = data.rows;
    });

    this.otherData.getUnitAssignments().subscribe(otherData => {
        this.dataSource.push({ assignments: otherData });
    });
}
```

Services Files

```
export interface xresponse {
  rows: Array < string > ,
}
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getUsers(): Observable<xResponse> {
  return this.http.get<xResponse>('/services/****/user/j**/******');
}
```

other Service

```
export interface yResponse {
    rows: Array<string> ,
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class yService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getyInfo(): Observable<yResponse> {
        return this.http.get<yResponse>('/services/c***/user/j****/*****');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that you need the response from both the services at once; if it is the case,
>   RxJS ***[ForkJoin](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61)*** is your friend! You can use `forkJoin` as follows -

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

submit() {
    const combined = forkJoin([
        this.data.getUsers(),
        this.otherData.getUnitAssignments()
    ]);
    combined.subscribe((response) => {
        // you will get 2 arrays in response
        this.dataSource.push(response[0].rows);
        this.dataSource.push(response[1].rows);
    });
}
```

- **FYI**, *`forkJoin` waits for each http request to complete and group’s all the observables returned by each http call into a single observable array and finally return that observable array.*

Comment: Thanks the only thing is when I try to access them from the coulumns the way the data table works it doesnt seem to be working:
`<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container  matColumnDef="x">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>title1</mat-header-cell>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let first" >{{first[0].rows}}</td>
</ng-container>
      <ng-container  matColumnDef="y">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>title2</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let second">{{second[1].rows}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>`

Comment: Try to debug your code & *ensure that you are putting right responses in `dataSource`*. I just shown `response[x].rows`, but it may be different in your case

Answer (score 1):

<strike>One solution is to use the RxJs [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) operator to combine the responses from all services:</strike>

```
submit() {
  combineLatest(
    this.service1.getData(),
    this.service2.getData(),
    this.service3.getData()
  ).subscribe(allData => ...)
}
```

**Edit:** Upon further thought, I suggest that for this use case, where each HTTP request should complete, you use `forkJoin` as answered by Tushar Walzade. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41797505/3634032) gives a concise explanation of what the difference is between `forkJoin` and `combineLatest`.

Comment: Thanks Just tested it out and it combined them for me. but When I try to access the data for service1 for column 1 and service2 for coulumn 2 in the table I'm having trouble accessing the data for of [0] and of [1]. but  I'm still debugging. I think its relatd to the publick interface I defined in my services

Answer (score 1):

You could use RxJs [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator. This way you will construct your `dataSource` only when all responses will be received (as it said in official docs it works similar to `Promise.all`):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin([this.data.getUsers(), this.otherData.getUnitAssignments()])
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.firstRequestResult = result[0];
            this.secondRequestResult = result[1];
            //building your dataSource here

        });
}
```