# Angular 9 RxJs using zip

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am not really comfortable with `rxjs` but I am trying to learn!
I have (potentially) two http calls I have to make when registering a user, if any of them fail, I want to warn the user. If creating the user fails, then I don't want it to execute the next http call.

I thought it would work like this:

```
public onSubmit(): void {
  this.loading = true;

  var user = {
    userName: this.f.email.value,
    email: this.f.email.value,
  };

  var observables = [
    this.userService.create(user, `${location.origin}/add-password`),
  ];
  var brandName = this.f.brand.value;
  var brand = this.brands.find((brand) => brand.name === brandName);

  if (brand) {
    observables.push(this.brandService.create(brand));
  }

  zip(observables).subscribe(
    () => {
      this.loading = false;
    },
    (response: any) => this.handleValidationError(response, this.snackBar)
  );
}
```

But when I submit my application, the subscription is never resolved.
I am sure that what I am doing wrong is very simple to fix, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  this.loading = true;

  var user = {
    userName: this.f.email.value,
    email: this.f.email.value,
  };

  this.userService.create(user, `${location.origin}/add-password`)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        var brandName = this.f.brand.value;
        var brand = this.brands.find((brand) => brand.name === brandName);

        return brand ? this.brandService.create(brand) : of(null)
      })
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    }, (response: any) => this.handleValidationError(response, this.snackBar));
```

`switchMap` is like a middleware before the `subscribe` will be called if the `this.userService.create` worked successfully.
It will return an `observable`, so if the brand is available it will run the `this.brandService.create(brand)` but if not, it will just return observable of null.

Comment: I appreciate you giving me an alternative to zip :) thanks dude

Comment: @r3plica, just thought that would be more simple syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an unkindly response, I managed to get it done like this:

```
public onSubmit(): void {
  this.loading = true;

  var brandName = this.f.brand.value;
  var brand = this.brands.find((brand) => brand.name === brandName);
  var createUser = this.userService.create(
    {
      userName: this.f.email.value,
      email: this.f.email.value,
    },
    `${location.origin}/add-password`
  );

  if (!brand) {
    var createBrand = this.brandService.create(brand);

    zip(createUser, createBrand).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.loading = false;
      },
      (response: any) => this.handleValidationError(response, this.snackBar)
    );
  } else {
    createUser.subscribe(
      () => {
        this.loading = false;
      },
      (response: any) => this.handleValidationError(response, this.snackBar)
    );
  }
}
```

As I mentioned before, rxjs is new to me, so I am not sure this is the best way to handle it. But it does work.

Comment: hope you aren't referring to my comment ;) - basically you can't pass an array to `zip`, but by spreading it it's possible