# difference between forkjoin and combineLatest rxjs

Tags: rxjs, observable, fork-join, combinelatest

Both are used to join multiple streams.

[From this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797439/rxjs-observable-combinelatest-vs-observable-forkjoin#:%7E:text=forkJoin%20%2D%20When%20all%20observables%20complete,unsubscribe%20from%20combineLatest%20unlike%20forkJoin.)
I am confused between both, I read combineLatest make calls in sync mode and forkJoin calls parallel,

I am trying this

```
combineLatest([
      of(null).pipe(delay(5000)),
      of(null).pipe(delay(5000)),
      of(null).pipe(delay(5000))
    ]).subscribe(() => console.log(new Date().getTime() - start));

forkJoin([
      of(null).pipe(delay(5000)),
      of(null).pipe(delay(5000)),
      of(null).pipe(delay(5000))
    ]).subscribe(() => console.log(new Date().getTime() - start));
```

that prints

```
5004
5014
```

every time result is arround 5 sec, if combineLatest sends request in sequence then why it is printing duration arround 5 sec.

Is this correct or there is any other difference, any example code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both subscribe to all source Observables in parallel and whether they are asynchronous depends only on each source Observable.

So in this use-case you'll get the same result. If you used `concat()` instead you would see difference because `concat()` subscribes to sources in sequence one after antother.

The difference between `forkJoin` and `combineLatest` is that `forkJoin` will emit only once when all source Observable emit at least one item and complete while `combineLatest` will emit every time any of the source Observables emit after they've emitted at least once.

Comment: by mistake i was using combineLatest with two http calls, but in that case i was getting result only once, so if combinelatest emits everytime when one of source emit then i should get two calls?

Comment: `combineLatest` will emit every time any of the source Observables emit **after they've emitted at least once.**

Comment: concat  i guess deprecated now?

Comment: `concat` isn't deprecated. Depending on what version of RxJS you use it might be imported as `import { concatWith } from 'rxjs';` or with v6 `import { concat } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: so forkJoin will not get call if  sources emit the second value?

Comment: `forkJoin` will emit only once after all sources complete with the latest value from each source Observable.